# Trying to InsertData or UpsertData using SSJS and I getting error message "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame."

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm working on a custom Subscription Management page using CloudPages, and I'm able to update existing subscriptions in the target data extension using SSJS just fine:

```
var updateResults = Platform.Function.UpdateData(data_extension, ["Market", "Department_Name", "Campaign_Name"], [market, department, campaign_name], ["LastSetBy", "Subscription_Status", "AsOfDate"], ["Custom Unsub", status, Now()]);
```

But this doesn't work given the nature of these subscriptions (opt-out for our customers) I need to be able to insert new records, and this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
var upsertResults = Platform.Function.UpsertData(data_extension, 4, "Market", market, "Department_Name", department, "EmailAddress", emailAddress, "Campaign_Name", campaign_name, "ClientID", client_id, "LastSetBy", "Custom Unsub", "Subscription_Status", status, "AsOfDate", Now());
```

It gives me an error message:

> Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

I also tried a direct InsertData, but this doesn't work:

```
var insertResults = Platform.Function.InsertData(data_extension, "Market", market, "Department_Name", department, "EmailAddress", emailAddress, "Campaign_Name", campaign_name, "ClientID", client_id, "LastSetBy", "Custom Unsub", "Subscription_Status", status, "AsOfDate", Now());
```

It gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're writing it like AMPScript, and [SSJS UPSERT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertData.htm) is different syntax. Which is why the Update works (correct syntax) but the UPSERT and INSERT don't.

For example, below is a valid UPSERT:

```
<script runat="server">
     var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertData("CustomerData",["ID"],["12345"],["Company","Country","Region"],["exampleCompany","USA","West"]);
</script>
```

It goes like this:

`Platform.Function.UpsertData( deName, ["whereClauseColumn1", "whereClauseColumn2"], ["whereClauseValue1","whereClauseValue2"], ["upsertColumn1", "upsertColumn2"], ["upsertValue1","upsertValue2"])`

Comment: I can't believe I was looking at the wrong documentation for my example code!  Thanks for a perfect answer.