# Copy the data extension records into another data extension using Ampscript or SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

Can we copy the records of one data extension into another data extension using ampscript/SSJS? If yes, kindly let me know the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create one script to duplicate your data extension, you can use [WSProxy to do this](https://gortonington.com/wsproxy-to-copy-a-data-extension/) (Retrieve DE info call, Retrieve Fields call then Create DE call) and then [create](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227206/creating-query-definition-with-ssjs) and [perform](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227206/creating-query-definition-with-ssjs) query activities via SSJS to fill in the newly created data extension.

Simple example of the create then execute script for Query:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1") ;

var deName = {{yourTargetDEName}}

var queryName = {{yourQueryName}}

var queryDef = { Name : queryName,

CustomerKey : queryName,
TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
TargetType : "DE",

Target:{
Name: deName,
CustomerKey : deName
},
QueryText : "SELECT {{myField}} FROM {{mySourceDE}}"
};

var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);

sleep(3000); //Wait for 3 seconds
//This helps ensure creation is complete before attempting to execute

var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("myQueryDef");
var status = qd.Perform();


function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would never use neither Ampscript nor SSJS to copy data across data extensions. Both from performance and from configuration perspective, [Query Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) in [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5) are far superior.

The only case, where I use SSJS for updating data, is when I need to update a list (e.g. All Subscribers) based on data in a data extension.

Comment: I understand we can use the Query activity in automation studio. But as per our requirement, As a part of deployment process we need to create 5 new data extension and then move all the records to new data extension. Sometimes its a time consuming process. So thought like to leverage the SSJS functionality to perform this activity.

Comment: This is indeed a very broad question, a number of examples have been provided here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227239/trying-to-insertdata-or-upsertdata-using-ssjs-and-i-getting-error-message-unabl and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279552/ssjs-to-save-data-into-a-data-extension/279560